# Creating scores for an action in a separate table in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scoring

I can create a Game, in that Game I can create Rules, I have a
button that "Completes" the Rule, by changing the Rule boolean
:completed column to false, which pushes it to the "Rules Completed"
view, I have a button that "renews" the Rule, by changing the Rule
boolean :completed column back to true.

So, my next task is to create a create method in the new Score controller that:

1. Via the same "Completed" button_to action,
2. Finds the rule of that button_to and inserts that rule ID to a new
   table, Score, in column "rule_id".
3. It also posts the time of completion (the time the user hits the
   button) to the Score table, column "complete_time",

What I have tried is to simply copy most of the details of the create
method in the Rule controller, which is:

```
def create
 @rule = @game.rules.new(params[:rule])
 if @rule.save
   flash[:notice] = "You have added a Rule to your Game!"
redirect_to game_url(@game)
else
 flash[:error] = "We couldn't add your Rule."
 redirect_to game_url(@game)
end
end
```

My latest efforts at repeating this is to post the rule_id to the Score table, column "rule_id" as follows:

```
def create
 @rule = Rule.find(params[:id])
 @score = @rule.scores.new(params[:rule_id])
 if @score.save
   flash[:notice] = "You scored!"
    redirect_to game_url(@game)
else
 flash[:error] = "Wide right, try again."
 redirect_to game_url(@game)
end
end
```

my new score db is:

```
class CreateScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :scores do |t|
     t.integer :rule_id
     t.datetime :completed_time

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

my proposed Score button action is:

```
<%= button_to "Score!", score_path(@game.id,rule.id) %>
```

and routes are set as:

```
Tgom::Application.routes.draw do

 resources :games do
   resources :rules do
  resources :scores do
end
   end
 end

  match 'games/:game_id/rules/:id/complete' => 'rules#complete', :as => :complete_rule

 match 'games/:game_id/rules/:rule_id/scores' => 'scores#create', :as => :score

 match 'games/:game_id/rules/:id/uncomplete' => 'rules#uncomplete', :as =>   :uncomplete_rule

 root :to => 'games#index'
```

The current error for this setup is reading:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ScoresController#create

Couldn't find Rule without an ID

Rails.root: c:/Sites/tgom
app/controllers/scores_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

your request via `score_path` url (as per your route) will set `:game_id` and `:rule_id` params.
In particular if you press the button for

```
<%= button_to "Score!", score_path(@game.id,rule.id) %>
```

`params[:game_id]` will be `@game.id` and `params[:rule_id]` will be `rule.id`

But your scores controller create method is reading `params[:id]`, which will be nil, hence your error.